# Calculate value from last day and same branch of the company

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sum

I need help to calculate the value of the daily goal minus the value of the difference for the next day, that is, for each branch of the company, there is the value of the goal and the value of sales. If on 01 I hit my goal, on the 02 the goal value will be lower (the difference value is in the image below).

Therefore, according to the image below, if on day 01 of branch 10, my goal was 6129.10 and I sold 7397, the difference for that day will be -1267.9, so on day 02 the goal value should be 6129.10 + (-1267.9) = 4861.13. How do I do this in T-SQL?

```
Before:

DT  ID_FILIAL   VL_SALES    VL_GOAL VL_DIFFERENCE
01/12/2020  10   7.397,00    6.129,10   -1.267,90 
01/12/2020  11   11.129,00   10.322,60  -806,40 
01/12/2020  12   23.690,00   20.967,80  -2.722,20 
02/12/2020  10   8.403,00    6.129,03   -2.273,97 
02/12/2020  11   9.871,00    10.322,58   451,58 
02/12/2020  12   20.559,00   20.967,74   408,74 


After:

DT  ID_FILIAL   VL_SALES    VL_GOAL VL_DIFFERENCE
01/12/2020  10   7.397,00    6.129,10   -1.267,90 
01/12/2020  11   11.129,00   10.322,60  -806,40 
01/12/2020  12   23.690,00   20.967,80  -2.722,20 
02/12/2020  10   8.403,00    4.861,13   -3.541,87 
02/12/2020  11   9.871,00    9.516,18   -354,82 
02/12/2020  12   20.559,00   18.245,54  -2.313,46
```

[image: Example:]

Comment: 1) Please don't use images for data, use formatted text. And if you want to make things really easy for those assisting you add the DDL/DML to create sample data. 2) Please show us what you have tried and got stuck on. You might be looking for a window function such as lag.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't paste as formatted text, I'll try to insert instead. I tried using JOIN with the same one table and using ROW NUMBER() but with no success, so I need some ideas.

Comment: @DaleK thank you for the tips, I updated the question and got the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a window sum:

```
select t.*,
    sum(vl_goal - vl_sales) over(partition by id_filial) + vl_sales as new_vgoal,
    sum(vl_goal - vl_sales) over(partition by id_filial) as new_vl_difference
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem is that the first row should be the VL_GOAL original, not the new goal. Is that any way?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(vl_sales - vl_goal) over (partition by id_filial order by dt) as vl_difference
from t;
```